# first few element of recycler view not showing

Tags: android

I implemented  nested Recyclerview with cardView and i am using piccaso for showing images , 
here is my code
HomeScreen.kt

```
class HomeScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
private var mRecylerview: RecyclerView? = null
private var mLayoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
private var mAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>? = null


private var genreDataset: ArrayList<HashMap<Int, String>>? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen)
    // intilizing genre dataset
    genreDataset = ArrayList<HashMap<Int, String>>()
    // request for genre list
    getGenrelist()


    // setting Recycler View

    mRecylerview = findViewById(R.id.genrebox) as RecyclerView?
    mRecylerview?.setHasFixedSize(true)


    //setting Layout Manager
    mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    mRecylerview?.layoutManager = mLayoutManager

    //setting adapter

    mAdapter = GenreboxAdapter(this, genreDataset!!)
    mRecylerview?.adapter = mAdapter

}

fun getGenrelist(): ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>? {

    var RequesQue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    // url for genre
    var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=key&language=en-US"

    var jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            object : Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
                override fun onResponse(p0: JSONObject?) {

                    parseGenrejsonIntoArraylist(p0)
                    Log.d("HOME", genreDataset?.toString())
                }

            }, object : Response.ErrorListener {
        override fun onErrorResponse(error: VolleyError) {

            Log.e("HOMESCREEN", "genre Request didnot work! ")
        }
    })

    RequesQue.add(jsonRequest)
    return null

}

private fun parseGenrejsonIntoArraylist(response: JSONObject?) {

    if (response != null) {
        try {


            var Genres = response.getJSONArray("genres")

            for (i in 0..Genres?.length()!! - 1) {
                Log.d("HOME", i.toString())
                var genreobj = Genres.getJSONObject(i)
                var Gid = genreobj.get("id")
                var Gname = genreobj.get("name")
                var genre = HashMap<Int, String>()
                genre.put(Gid as Int, Gname as String)
                genreDataset?.add(genre)
            }

        } catch (exception: JSONException) {
            Log.e("HOMESCREEN", "genre Request didnot work! ")
        }
    }



}

}
```

GenreboxAdapter.kt

```
 class GenreboxAdapter(internal var context: Context, Moviesdataset: ArrayList<HashMap<Int, String>>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GenreboxAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

internal var genredataset: ArrayList<HashMap<Int, String>>
var genrename: String? = null
var genreid: Int? = null



init {
    genredataset = Moviesdataset


}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, i: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.genrebox, parent, false)
    val v = ViewHolder(view)
    return v
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, i: Int) {
    for (key in genredataset.get(i).keys) {
        genreid = key
        genrename = genredataset.get(i).get(key)

        viewHolder.setAdapter(genrename!!, genreid!!,getmoviesfromgenre(key,viewHolder))


    }

}

private fun getmoviesfromgenre(id: Int?,holder:ViewHolder): java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<Int, String>> {
    var dataset = java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<Int, String>>()


    val url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/$id/movies?api_key=key&language=en-US&include_adult=true&sort_by=created_at.asc"
    val jsObjRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response -> dataset = parsemovies(response,dataset,holder) }, Response.ErrorListener {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    })
    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest)
    holder.innerAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    return dataset as java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<Int, String>>
}

private fun parsemovies(response: JSONObject,data: ArrayList<HashMap<Int, String>>?,holder: ViewHolder): java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<Int, String>> {
    try {

        // Getting JSON Array node
        val movies = response.getJSONArray("results")

        // looping through All Contacts
        for (i in 0..movies.length() - 1) {
            val movie = movies.getJSONObject(i)
            val m = java.util.HashMap<Int, String>()
            m.put(movie.getInt("id"), movie.getString("poster_path"))
//                Log.d("HOME", m.toString())
            data?.add(m)



        }
    } catch (e: JSONException) {

    }

    return data!!
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return genredataset.size
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var innerRecyclerView: RecyclerView
        internal set
    public var innerAdapter: card_layout_adapter? = null

    init {

        innerRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieRecyler) as RecyclerView


    }

  fun setAdapter(name: String, id: Int,data:ArrayList<HashMap<Int, String>>?) {

        innerAdapter = card_layout_adapter(id, name, context,data)
        innerRecyclerView.adapter = innerAdapter
        innerRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context.applicationContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

  }


}
}
```

and  class card_layout_adapter.java

```
 public class card_layout_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
String name;
int id;
private ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>> dataset = null;


public card_layout_adapter(Integer id, String name, Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, String>>  dataset) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.context = context;
    this.dataset = dataset;
    Log.d(" fgdf","" +dataset.size());


}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    Log.d(" fgdf","" +dataset.size());

    if (i == 0) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.genretitle, parent, false);
        ViewHolder1 vh = new ViewHolder1(v);

        return vh;

    } else {



        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.customcardview, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }
}



@Override
public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {


    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            ViewHolder1 v1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;
            break;
        default:

            ViewHolder v = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
            String url;

            if (dataset.size() > 0) {
                for (Integer key : dataset.get(i - 1).keySet()) {
                    url = dataset.get(i - 1).get(key);
                    Picasso.with(context).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/" + url).into(v.img);

                }


            }
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 20;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTitle;
    public ImageView img;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.poster);


    }



}

public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mGenre;

    public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mGenre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        mGenre.setText(name);
    }

}
}
```

but it is not working properly it showing result  like this

[when app opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHof2.png)

[after scrolling image become visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps6W8.jpg)

Comment: It's me or this is a little tricky `for (i in 0..movies.length() - 1) {`

Comment: its fine i checked